"Failed to Launch JVM" after packaging
"Failed to Launch JVM"
This error only occurs after packaging and trying to execute the exe, after installing the msi.
the error will only exist if i put a db connection in the code
im using: gradle 8.5
kotlin: 1.9.22
compose:1.6.0
exposed: 0.49.0


object Messages : Table() {
    val message = varchar("message", length = 50)
}

@Composable
@Preview
fun App() {
    MaterialTheme {
        Surface {
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Box(
                    modifier =
                    Modifier
                        .width(150.dp)
                        .background(Color(0xFF424242))
                        .fillMaxHeight()

                ) {
                    Column(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxHeight()
                            .padding(all = 30.dp),
                    ) {
                        Text("Devices")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

fun main() {
    val url = "URL"
    val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"
    val user = "USER"
    val password = "MYPASSWORD"

    try {
        Database.connect(url, driver, user, password)
    } catch (e: ExposedSQLException) {
        LoggerFactory.getLogger("Main").error("Error connecting to the database", e)
    }
    transaction {
        SchemaUtils.create(Messages)

        Messages.insert {
            it[Messages.message] = "Test2"
            println("Inserted message: ${message.table}")
        }
    }
    application {
        Window(
            title = "Multiplatform App",
            state = rememberWindowState(width = 1000.dp, height = 1000.dp),
            onCloseRequest = ::exitApplication,
        ) {
            window.minimumSize = Dimension(350, 600)
            App()
        }}

}

I tried removing the db, and it works perfectly fine, the error really just occurs after putting any db connection in the code.
I tried changing the db aswell, before using postgresql, i was using mongodb, and still the same error.

Fixed by adding the line below into the build.gradle.kts:
modules("java.compiler", "java.instrument" , "java.sql", "jdk.unsupported", "java.management")


in your gradle file
add the line  includeAllModules = true
compose.desktop {
    application {
        mainClass = "MainKt"

        nativeDistributions {
            includeAllModules = true // add this line
            targetFormats(TargetFormat.Dmg, TargetFormat.Msi, TargetFormat.Deb)
            packageName = "your package name"
            packageVersion = "1.0.0"
        }
    }
}

This worked for me.
